# What am I doing wrong trying to get data with URLLoader?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

Hey, I have a php document dynamicly generating the following:

```
peerID=e224d6cac76ef3181d4804858d82ebeee7e67ad7bdd7b02f3857a700b0ec7fbc
```

(from get_peerID.php)
I'm using the following AS3 to try and get this data:

```
private var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();    
private function sendData():void {
                writeText("sending data...");
                var objSend:Object = new Object;
                objSend.peerID = myID.text;
                put_peerID.send( objSend );
                writeText("http://localhost/example.com/scripts/get_peerID.php?peerID=" + myID.text);
                var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/example.com/scripts/get_peerID.php?peerID=" + myID.text);
                myRequest.contentType = "text/plain"; 
                //var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
                configureListeners(myLoader); //.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
                myLoader.load(myRequest);


            }

            private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
                dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            }

            private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {                
                writeText("completeHandler: " + myLoader.data.peerID);
            }

            private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
                writeText("openHandler: " + event);
            }

            private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
                writeText("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
            }

            private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
                writeText("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
            }

            private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
                writeText("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
            }

            private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
                writeText("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
            }
```

Which generates the following text (from `writeText()`):

```
 sending data...
http://localhost/example.com/scripts/get_peerID.php?peerID=5131079b60ba3ae05f9d54568896db1e04f772f97bb98c6d525cb8ba3032798b
openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=200 responseURL=null]
```

So, its not giving me the data that I need. I'm not sure what to try next. I've been in and out of forums all day so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The AS code looks good to me. My gut feeling is that there's a problem with the php. run a `trace(myRequest);` and try it outside flash (looking at the code, you are doing a GET, so just stick the trace result in the browser) and then report.

Comment: I tried to add `trace(myRequest);` after `myLoader.load(myRequest);` but I don't no how to see the results? I'm in flash builder.

Comment: well just stick in this trace line right after `var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/example.com/scripts/get_peerID.php?peerID=" + myID.text);`. Results will show in the 'Console' panel i believe.

Comment: Hm...still can't figure it out. Do you think if I do a release build it might work? Would it have anything to do with that?

Comment: Adobe says...
For Flash Player 8 and later:

Data loading is not allowed if the calling file is in the local-with-file-system sandbox and the target resource is from a network sandbox.
Data loading is also not allowed if the calling file is from a network sandbox and the target resource is local.

Does this mean that this won't work on my localhost?

Comment: thats it. the code works when deployed outside of my local host. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because I was running it on my localhost. Adobe says:
For Flash Player 8 and later:

- Data loading is not allowed if the
  calling file is in the
  local-with-file-system sandbox and
  the target resource is from a network
  sandbox.
- Data loading is also not allowed if
  the calling file is from a network
  sandbox and the target resource is
  local.

After released it and put it up online it work.